# Can users upload files to separate folders?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am going to have a bunch of users uploading files in my drupal 7 site.  I would like each user to upload their files to separate folders, instead of all the files going to the private/downloads.

Is this an possible in drupal 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In your file upload field settings page, set the "File directory" field to use a user token (uid, name, email, or anything you need)

It would be like: `private/[current-user:uid]` or `private/[current-user:name]`

Hope this helps.